# How to resolve TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'page_size' while using google cloud storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, anaconda3, google-cloud-storage

I have been trying to read from gcs with the following code:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
len(list(client.list_blobs('mybucket', prefix='dir1/dir2')))
```

however i get the following error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-81a6f9416437> in <module>
----> 1 len(list(client.list_blobs('mybucket', prefix='dir1/dir2')))

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py in list_blobs(self, bucket_or_name, max_results, page_token, prefix, delimiter, start_offset, end_offset, include_trailing_delimiter, versions, projection, fields, page_size, timeout, retry)
   1296             page_size=page_size,
   1297             timeout=timeout,
-> 1298             retry=retry,
   1299         )
   1300         iterator.bucket = bucket

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py in _list_resource(self, path, item_to_value, page_token, max_results, extra_params, page_start, page_size, timeout, retry)
    396             extra_params=extra_params,
    397             page_start=page_start,
--> 398             page_size=page_size,
    399         )
    400 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'page_size'
```

I am using Python 3.7.6 and have updated google cloud packages. currently on the following versions:

```
google-cloud-storage==2.4.0
google-cloud-core==2.3.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried to replicate your error and found out that your `google-api-core` package has a version lower than 1.28.0
[image]

You must update to a newer version greater than 1.29.0.
[image]

Using this command:

```
pip install google-api-core==1.30.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-core
```

Woks for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32854489)

Comment: It seems that my answer only includes one command for upgrade package without any link. Is this comment in the wrong place? @AmitGupta